# Regular Google Drive/Gmail On-Premise Backup using Google API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

Is that possible to on-premise backup my domain user's google drive/gmail regularly using Google API with a service account? If so, which Google API should i use? I have been searching for this problem almost a week. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are APIs for both Google Drive (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) and (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/).  But neither API has a backup operation; you have to build it yourself.

For Gmail, see the "full synchronization" information here:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync  This is a good starting point for keeping a Gmail mailbox in sync with your local, on-premise backup.

For Google Drive, see "download files" (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) and "detect changes" (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-changes).